# SSRS Data Manipulation in Rows

Tags: reporting-services, copy

I've below data.

```
SRNO    Date            Credit  Debit   ClosingBal  OpeningBal
1       01 Oct 2017     10000   100     9900        0
2       02 Oct 2017     20000   200     29700       9900
3       03 Oct 2017     30000   300     59400       29700
4       04 Oct 2017     40000   400     99000       59400
5       05 Oct 2017     50000   500     148500      99000
```

Here I'm manipulating two columns ClosingBal and OpeningBal. 
Closing Bal is difference between credit and debit + Last days balance.

I need to show opening balance such as last days' closing balance. i.e. in 1st row opening balance is always 0(Zero) and from second row data is just copied from Row[i]Column[j] to Row[i+1]Column[j].

Need help.

Comment: What actual data do you have in your database (or wherever the data comes from) Do you just have SRNO; Date; Credit; Debit ? And do you want to do this work in SSRS or in SQL. Please state which versions of reporting services and database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only actually have SRNO; Date; Credit and Debit in your dataset then you can do the following.

I used the following to reproduce your sample dataset and called it `DataSet1`

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(SRNO int, TranDate Date, Credit int, Debit int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '20171001', 10000, 100),
(2, '20171002', 20000, 200),
(3, '20171003', 30000, 300),
(4, '20171004', 40000, 400),
(5, '20171005', 50000, 500)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then created a simple table showing all four columns plus two additional column, one for `closingbal` and one for `openingbal`.

Set `ClosingBal` expression to:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Credit.Value-Fields!Debit.Value, Sum, "DataSet1")
```

Set `OpeningBal` expression to

```
=Previous(RunningValue(Fields!Credit.Value-Fields!Debit.Value, Sum, "DataSet1"))
```

This gives us the following output.
[image]

If you need a zero in the first column then the expression has to change to this.

```
=IIF(
    Previous(RunningValue(Fields!Credit.Value-Fields!Debit.Value, Sum, "DataSet1"))=Nothing
    ,0
    ,Previous(RunningValue(Fields!Credit.Value-Fields!Debit.Value, Sum, "DataSet1"))
)
```

Which then gives us this output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I've implemented same solution.